Heap Corruption C++ when using QByteArray with QDataStream
I have a function with the following signature
bool TraceData::Read(const QSharedPointer<QDataStream>& dataStream, const int formatCode
                     , const int numberOfSamples)

It gets called with dataStream positioned at the correct place.
Now I need to extract floating point numbers from the data stream,but am getting a heap corruption exception and I don't know why.
I am using a loop for this purpose
for (auto index = 0; index < numberOfSamples; ++index)
{
    QByteArray buffer{};
    auto cc = dataStream->readRawData(buffer.data(), sizeof(float));
    auto ff = qFromBigEndian<float>(buffer.data());
}

Now when I step through using the debugger 'ff' is set to the expected value but when I step over the line I get this
enter image description here
I cannot spot what is causing this

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdatastream.html#readRawData The buffer s must be preallocated what is wrong with reading documentation ? You read to empty buffer.

This is a complex way of writing datastream >> some_float_variable. Why not that? Know that you can set the byte order of QDataStream and that it defaults to big endian.

@Botje
That was my original plan, but it gives me the wring value

Are you sure the data is written in big endian format and not little endian?

Your QByteArray buffer has zero size for data. Anyway you are reading data in strange way, QDataStream is able to handle any endian without extra code. You need just properly configure it (it has lots of options)

You believe in a magic QByteBuffer that is automatically going to resize based on the data that is being read into it. But all readRawData has is a pointer so it's impossible for it to resize the buffer. That's a job for you before you call readRawData.

Also this QSharedPointer<QDataStream> is strange thing to do (bad practice). I would use QDataStream as a local variable.

@MarekR - why is this a bad idea?

see examples how QDataStream should be used in QDataStream doc or some full example.

Here is better way, by using transaction to read this:
void DataReader::readyReadSlot() // connected to QIODevice::readyRead
{
    QDataStream in{qobject_cast<QIODevice *>(sender())};
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_7);
    in.setFloatingPointPrecision(QDataStream::SinglePrecision);
    in.setByteOrder(QDataStream::BigEndian);

    qint32 a; // not integer typedef which has fixed size!
    float x;
    in.startTransaction();
    in >> a >> x; // this may fail so next condition checks this

    if (!in.commitTransaction()) // try commit transaction
        return;     // wait for more data signaled by QIODevice::readyRead, 

    SomeDataType result{a ,x};
    emit messageRecived(result); // signal outcome
}

Use of extra QByteArray is not needed.
I had to fill gaps, but you should get the pattern to make this better.

As suggested by rafix07 I simply forgot to initialize the buffer
buffer.reserve(sizeof(float));


reserve is incorrect, after that the buffer still has zero size. You need to resize the buffer. You might be abke to get away with reserve but it's still incorrect.

Actually a simpler and more efficient thing would be to forget about QByteArray and just declare a plain array. char buffer[sizeof(float)];

You just needed to properly create your buffer: QByteArray buffer(sizeof(float), '0');.

I hope this Read function is not directly called in parallel; shared pointers are not meant to be passed by reference, unless the pointer itself is supposed to retarget another object - in which case it wouldn't be const
